# Android FaceBook newMyFriendsRequest Returns EMPTY Friends List

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, parse-platform

I'm developing my first Android App using Parse and Facebook, so I'm pretty new to it.

I'm trying to retrieve the User's Friend List with `Request.newMyFriendsRequest()` but it gives me an empty list when testing with real users.

As far as I know, with `Graph API v2.0` this request only will return the set of the person's friends who also use the app.

For that purpose I created a fake Fb profile, I became friend with him in Facebook with my real profile, installed my app, registered with `ParseUser` and Linked with Facebook using `ParseFacebookUtils.link` with both profiles, but the Request returns an **empty list of friends**.

I've created several **Test Users** in Facebook's App dashboard, and simulated several friendships between them. I made the same process in my app (register with `parseUser`, link with `ParseFacebookUtils.link`) with two of them, and the list `users.size()` **returns 2 friends as expected.**

Why it doesn't work with my actual profile and the fake one (which is like any other real one)??

This is how I'm linking profiles:

```
List<String> permissions = new ArrayList<String>();
permissions.add("public_profile");
permissions.add("user_friends");

ParseFacebookUtils.link(currentUser, permissions, MainActivity.this, new SaveCallback() {
     @Override
     public void done(ParseException ex) {
          if (ParseFacebookUtils.isLinked(currentUser)) {
             Log.d(TAG, "Woohoo, user logged in with Facebook!");
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Facebook succesfully linked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          }
          if (ex != null) {
             Log.d (TAG, ex.getLocalizedMessage() + "\n + Exception Code: " + ex.getCode());
          }
     });
```

And this how I Request friends:

```
Request.newMyFriendsRequest(ParseFacebookUtils.getSession(), new GraphUserListCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onCompleted(List<GraphUser> users, Response response) {
         Log.d(TAG, "Request Completed!! " + response.toString() + "----" + users.size());
         if (users != null) {
             List<String> friendsList = new ArrayList<String>();
             for (GraphUser user : users) {
                friendsList.add(user.getId());
             }
         }
    }
}).executeAsync();.
```

But I can't figure out how to get the friends list of a real user. With my profile it should return 1 friend who is also registered using the app being developed...

Comment: Have both users grated user_friends permission to the app?

Comment: That was it! I guess that on those real users I linked with FB before I added the permission request for user_friends in the login.

I unlinked the parse profile out of Facebook, Logged out the user, but whenever I try to Login and Link again it doesn't ask me for permissions, and instead tried to open the last session but it responded **Expired or invalid token**. It seems that Parse isn't actually unlinking the user from facebook. 
Thanks!

Comment: same problem...how about resolve?

Comment: I couldn´t fix it that time. I was starting the app, so I created a new one in Parse, and started fresh using the user_friends permission from the beginning... :(

Answer (score 1):

I got an empty array because of the following:

[- This will only return any friends who have used (via Facebook Login) the app making the request.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user/friends#readperms)

Please note!

Comment: yes, that is right. But the problem in this case was a problem refreshing the facebook user_friends permission to the app.
The first time I logged with that user I didn't have that permission set and when I did it, for some reason the permissions weren't being granted, and I had to refresh those permissions for them to start working again.